# Is it possible to have 2 master nodes?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, master-slave

is it possible to have a 2 master nodes? 1 having resource manager & 1 having node manager in yarn-environment
I am running 3 node cluster with yarn configuration. It gives me error as below in log file:

hadoop OpenJDK Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now. It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.

and some syslog like below

```
2014-12-09 11:36:16,138 INFO [Thread-65] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 55850
2014-12-09 11:36:16,143 INFO [IPC Server listener on 55850] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 55850
2014-12-09 11:36:16,143 INFO [IPC Server Responder] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2014-12-09 11:36:16,144 INFO [TaskHeartbeatHandler PingChecker] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.TaskHeartbeatHandler: TaskHeartbeatHandler thread interrupted
```

so, please give me some solution.

Comment: Did you install slave role and master on the same node?

Comment: yes, I have 1 node having master and slave role and 2 nodes having only slave role.

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 master node? and if possible than is it required to specify conf/masters with both node name in both node configuration?

Comment: I think you should not setup a node with both master and slave role. It can provok conflict. But I don't really understand about your "master" because you talk about ressource manager and node manager. Ressource manager is the master for yarn whereas node managers are slaves

Comment: so, if I stop node manager on master node (t.e. resource manager node) than can I run the program and will solve problem?